# How to Redirect only HTTP to subdomain in htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Recently i redirected my traffic from `www.xyz.co.in` to `top.xyz.co.in`.

I used below rules in my ".htaccess" configuration file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.xyz.co.in [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://top.xyz.co.in/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

This works fine.

Now i want to redirect my `https://xyz.co.in` traffic also to `https://top.xyz.com`.

How to do it? Please help.

Comment: "...also to `https://top.xyz.com`" - should that be `top.xyz.co.in`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you question right then what you actually ask is how to redirect traffic from *both* hostnames to the same target, from `www.xyz.co.in` and from `xyz.co.in`. I fail to understand what you are trying to say in the questions's title ("only HTTP"), since your example uses the `https` protocol, not `http`.

If so then you just need to make the "www." prefix in the host name optional to match requests to *both* hosts:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?xyz\.co\.in$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://top.xyz.co.in%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

(I also altered a few other details as a suggestion of improvements ...)

Comment: "to the same target" - but they've used a _different_ target domain in the second example (although whether that was intentional or just a typo is unclear).

Comment: @MrWhite I assumed that is a typo because of the phrasing "also to".